# "No such interface supported" after upgrading SourceSafe project to 2012 SSMS format.

Tags: sql-server-2012

We had SQL Server 2008 r2 project.
Then we converted it to SSMS 2012 format.
Now I can't open the converted project.
I am getting an error

C:\Views.ssmssqlproj : error  : Unexpected error encountered. It is recommended that you restart the application as soon as possible.

Error: No such interface supported
File: vsee\internal\inc\vscomptr.inl
Line number: 259

The older project was using SourceSafe 6. I wonder if it is the reason. SQL Server Management Studio 2012 doesn't support SourceSafe 6 anymore.

Comment: This is an error that is being experienced by a few of us. Please see:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/3a3094a5-a320-41ae-983c-ff08d8549754 and the Connect bug logged:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/737893/ssms-2012-error-adding-solution-to-source-control-with-tfs-msscci-provider# If you are experiencing the same you could add your weight to the discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has logged this issue:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2727824

and has included the fix starting in the following update:

2723749 Cumulative update package 3 for SQL Server 2012

According to Microsoft, this fix should be available in Service packs:

> *Microsoft SQL Server 2012 hotfixes are created for specific SQL Server service packs. You must apply a SQL Server 2012 Service Pack RTM hotfix to an installation of SQL Server 2012 Service Pack RTM. By default, any hotfix that is provided in a SQL Server service pack is included in the next SQL Server service pack.*

So, the [latest SQL Server 2012 service pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755533) contains the fix, and it worked for me.